# Classical Galois Theory and Groupoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory, groupoids

Given your favorite field $k$, we can build its groupoid of algebraic closures in the obvious way: Look at the category of all possible algebraic closures with field isomorphisms as the arrows.

This is interesting, because most topics in galois theory aren't functorial: we have to make a bunch of arbitrary choices (picking a root, etc.). Of course, we can "canonical-ify" this construction in the usual way -- just look at *all* choices at once. This feels like something that people would have thought about, but I'm struggling to find references for "elementary" galois theory done with groupoid machinery. Googling around it seems people are mainly talking about the absolute galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$ (a famously difficult object). This is interesting, but I would love to cut my teeth on something a bit simpler.

With that in mind, does anyone know of references for galois theory with groupoids, but pitched at a graduate student level rather than a research level? In particular, I would love to see splitting fields, finite galois extensions, etc. treated (if more advanced topics are treated, that's great too. But I would like to start with something I'm more familiar with).

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: I’m not really clear on what this is supposed to be gaining you. You still have to prove this groupoid is nonempty, and that will definitely require some arbitrary choices.

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly explain the issue with this question?

Comment: @KevinArlin -- The idea is that by making every arbitrary choice simultaneously the choice ceases to be arbitrary. You see this in, for instance, the fundamental groupoid of a space (which removes the arbitrary choice of basepoint).

Comment: Yeah, but there are concrete benefits to the fundamental groupoid. You no longer have to think about maps of pointed spaces, because the fundamental groupoid is functorial on the unpointed homotopy category, the real category of interest. I don't think the key issue with algebraic closures is that you have to choose *one* of them, it's that proving that *any* closure exists requires the axiom of choice in a heavy, not-unique-up-to-unique-isomorphism way. That's why I say I don't see the benefit here.

Comment: That's a reasonable critique. I'm still interested in references, though. Maybe the reason you've outlined is why I'm struggling to find any, but I know from conversations and blog posts I can't find anymore that it's something people have considered. I guess we'll see ^_^

Comment: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/159021) is a related question with answers on MO.